# Recursively Pass Template Template To a Template Template Function

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, typename, template-templates

It seems to me, that since in C++ we can pass a template template, then a function accepting a template template should be able to pass a (its) template template into itself. However this appears not to be the case.

```
template< typename PREVIOUS_TYPE_T, typename TYPE_T >
struct Node
{
    typedef TYPE_T TYPE;
    typedef PREVIOUS_TYPE_T PREVIOUS_TYPE;
    PREVIOUS_TYPE_T* previous;
    template< template< typename... > typename FUNCTOR_T, typename... CURRENT_ARGUMENTS_T >
    void DoCall() {
        previous->DoCall< FUNCTOR_T, TYPE_T, CURRENT_ARGUMENTS_T... >();
    }
};
```

Is there anyway to pass `FUNCTOR_T` above, or any work around to doing so?

Comment: I'm not sure, what was wrong with your original revision? The revisions could affect the answer. Could you clarify which one you actually mean and why?

Comment: @Chipster Thank you for your response. The original version was copy/pasted from an old file, not with the one I am currently working with which is what you see above. The old version had `template< typename... ARGUMENTS_T > typename FUNCTOR_T` and passes `ARGUMENTS_T` into the last (variadic) parameter of `DoCall` in the recursive call, which causes an obvious problem and isent what I am asking. What I am asking is: is there a way or work around to pass a template template parameter to a function called inside another function (or functor, etc.) to the effect of what is above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ARGUMENTS_T`. That name has no effect.

When you're passing a template template around, it's still a template with no parameters passed to it. There is no template parameter to extract from `std::plus`, as opposed to `std::plus<int>`.

Instead, use `CURRENT_ARGUMENTS_T`, which is what you intended to forward.

Also, you `previous` is a dependent type. You must desambiguate the template:

```
previous->template DoCall< FUNCTOR_T, TYPE_T, CURRENT_ARGUMENTS_T... >();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry, I had removed `ARGUMENTS_T` before but copy/pasted from the wrong place. However it still fails compilation on GCC and MSVC with the code you posted.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain see my edit

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, had to go, still reviewing your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful!!